# How to Specify DbContext Per User with AutoFac and ASP.Net Core

Tags: dependency-injection, asp.net-core, autofac, multi-tenant, dbcontext

I am building a multitenant application using ASP.Net Core and AutoFac. Each tenant will be assigned it's own database (e.g. TenantA will use DatabaseA, TenantB will use DatabaseB).

I want to use AutoFac to resolve which database to connect to at runtime.

I set things up in Startup.cs:

```
 public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();  

containerBuilder.RegisterType<TenantConnectionStringProvider>()
        .As<IConnectionStringProvider>()
        .WithParameter((paramInfo, componentContext) => paramInfo.Name == "tenantKey",
                  (paramInfo, componentContext) => userSession2.TenantKey)
                  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();

services.AddDbContext<TenantDataContext>(options => {
            var connectionStringProvider = new TenantConnectionStringProvider(userSession2.TenantKey);
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionStringProvider.ConnectionString); });

        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
}
```

Also:

```
public interface IConnectionStringProvider
{
    string ConnectionString { get; set; }
}

public class TenantConnectionStringProvider : IConnectionStringProvider
{
    private string _tenantKey;

    public TenantConnectionStringProvider(string tenantKey)
    {
        _tenantKey = tenantKey;
        ConnectionString = GetConnectionString(_tenantKey);
    }

    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

    public string GetConnectionString(string tenantKey)
    {
        if (tenantKey == "64C15227-8F9E-4AE4-8620-1986F051FB8F")
        {
            return "TenantA Connection String";
        }
        return "TenantB Connection String";
    }


}
```

Unfortunately the TenantDbContext is always set with the TenantA connection string. This happens even if I step through the code and manually set the return value of the tenantKey parameter so that it returns the TenantB connection string.

How can I get around this? How can I have Autofac resolve and create instances of DBContext based on the appropriate connection string for the current tenant?

Comment: Have you [seen this issue?](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection/issues/1)

Comment: Appreciate it @TravisIllig. I'll just close this issue.